# How to make esp8266 run only on coin cell battery only on press of a switch?

Tags: esp8266, batteries

I would like to have esp8266 off, and turn it on only when user presses a button. There would be about 4 different buttons connected to input pins. But each of the button should not only be connected to its input pin but also "somehow" turn on the esp8266 which would send via WiFi which button was pressed.

I am thinking about using coin cell battery and some super capacitor which would be charged and last for 10-20 seconds needed for esp8266 to send the information and then it would go off after energy in the capacitor is used up.

Is it possible and how would minimal circuit look like ?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/56890/wake-up-esp8266-from-deepsleep-with-a-button

Comment: @Juraj Well, I would rather have esp8266 turned off, because there is no purpose for having it runnning, even in the deep sleep mode. The button will be pressed maybe once in a week or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use double-switch push buttons. DPDT (double pole double throw) or DPST (double pole single throw):

[image]

<sup>Image Source: Researchgate.net</sup>

[image]

<sup>Image Source: RS UK</sup>

There are individual switches inside a single button. Once pressed these two independent switches will be closed.

One switch can be used for supply and the other can be used for logic input. So once the button is pressed the unit will get supply through one switch and also can read the logic input through the button.

I used the same approach in a coin-cell powered RF remote controller. The problem is that the software (or the initialisation, in general) should be fast enough to run the requested function in even a short-press duration.